# show the data in dropdown fetched from database using laravel 8

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu

i have to show the category values in dropdown in product form,the given code is from my view,the error is undefined $categories.this is my first code in laravel i dont know how to make changings in other files.which variable is used in foreach?or i have to create new function in ProductController?

```
<form action="/upload_product" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label>Choose Categories</label>
    <select name="category_id" id="category" class="category">
        <option disable selected>--select category--</option>
        @foreach($categories as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="number" name="sale_price" placeholder="sale_price">
   </form>
```

Model Product.php

```
        class Product extends Model
           {
     use HasFactory; 
     protected $table = 'products';
     public $timestamps = true;

    public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}
```

}
Model Category.php

```
   class Category extends Model
  {
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = [ 'name' ];
    protected $dates = [ 'deleted_at' ];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function products (){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
  }
}
```

ProductController.php

```
   <?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
 use App\Models\Product;
 use App\Models\Category;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{ 
  public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all(); 
    return view('products/index', ['products'=>$products]);
}
 public function view()
{
  $products = Product::with('category')->get(); 
  $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
  return view ('product.view')-> with([
    'products' => $products,
    'categories' => $categories,
]);
}
```

Comment: Which error comes from `view` or `index`?

Comment: undefined $categories from index file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like below

```
public function index(){
    $products   = Product::all(); 
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view('products.index', compact('products','categories'));
}
```

Comment: thank you but if i have to show the multiple dropdowns like units,brand then i have to make changings in this index function?

Comment: Yes you have to add others model data in `compact`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$categories` in your index file.
Based on the `index` method, you're sendig just products:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all(); 
    return view('products/index', ['products'=>$products]);
}
```

So add categories too.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function index()
{


 $products = Product::get(); 
    return view('products/index', ['products'=>$products]);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in three ways

```
public function index(){
    $products   = Product::all(); 
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view('products.index', compact('products','categories'));
}

public function index(){
    $products   = Product::all(); 
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view('products.index')->with(['products'=>$products,'categories'=>$categories]));
}

public function index(){
        $data['products']   = Product::all(); 
        $data['categories'] = Category::with('products')->get();
        return view('products.index',$data);
    }
```